# Let the cards guide you

Tags: knowledge, visual

**How does the "equations" below make sense?**

---

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think the right hand side indicates

> The number of countries in each continent with cardinal directions in their names for each of the cardinal directions (north, south, east, west).

In particular

> Asia contains the countries **North** Korea, **South** Korea and **East** Timor (Timor-Leste) so gets a '1' in each of the north, south and east directions.
>  Europe contains the country **North** Macedonia so gets a '1' in the north direction.
>  Africa contains the countries **South** Africa and **South** Sudan so gets a '2' in the south direction.

Title

> I guess 'cards' here is a hint to look at *cardinal* directions.

Comment: Yup correct, well done!